# Error while adding user designed object in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have to make a polynomial class `Polynom` that would extend a monomial class `Monom`. The objects in `Monom` can be both int or double so I thought I would use generics.

I tried making the `Polynom` by adding the `Monom` into an `ArrayList`. All fine, but I keep getting an error at `p1.add(m1);`:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete 
     MethodHeaderName
    - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration
    - Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete 
     QualifiedName
    - Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token
```

I searched everywhere and this should be the right syntax.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Polinom {

    Integer grad, coef = new Integer(0);
    Monom<Integer> m1= new Monom<Integer>(grad, coef);
    ArrayList<Monom<Integer>> p1 = new ArrayList<Monom<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Monom<Integer>> p2 = new ArrayList<Monom<Integer>>();

    p1.add(m1);

}
```

This is how the `Monom` class looks like:

```
public class Monom<T> {

    private T grad, coef;

    public Monom (T grad, T coef) {
        this.grad = grad;
        this.coef = coef;
    }
    public T getGrad() {
        return this.grad;
    }
    public T getCoef() {
        return this.coef;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to Java myself but I think you need to have p1.add(m1)  inside a method.  I don't know why.  That's just how Java works.

Comment: Put it inside a method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `p1.add(m1);` should be inside a method. For example

```
public void doSomething() {
    p1.add(m1);
}
```

Comment: This was my first question here. Thank you very much for all your help. It works!

Answer (score 2):

Have your Class polinom like this.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Polinom {

  Integer grad, coef = new Integer(0);
  Monom<Integer> m1= new Monom<Integer>(grad, coef);
  ArrayList<Monom<Integer>> p1 = new ArrayList<Monom<Integer>>();
  ArrayList<Monom<Integer>> p2 = new ArrayList<Monom<Integer>>();
  public void anyMethod()
  {
   p1.add(m1);
  }
}
```